# How do I overwrite stale partitioned data with AWS Glue job?

Tags: aws-glue

I have data that gets dumped once a day to *s3://<bucket>/mydata/year=*/month=*/*.snappy.parquet* as cumulative data for that month. I have a crawler that crawls it to update the *mydata* table and a CW rule that calls a lambda upon crawler success that starts a Glue job to transform the columns and output to *s3://<bucket>/mydata-transformed/year=*/month=*/*.snappy.parquet*. This flow basically works. However, the current problem I have is that the output data gets additively written instead of replacing what's there (because it's cumulative data for the month). For example, suppose at midnight on Oct 1,2020, data for 10/1 gets dumped into *s3://<bucket>/mydata/year=2020/month=10/*.snappy.parquet*. The flow will produce transformed data in *s3://<bucket>/mydata-transformed/year=2020/month=10/*.snappy.parquet*, everything is good for 10/1 data. However, the next day when data for 10/1 and 10/2 gets dumped into *s3://<bucket>/mydata/year=2020/month=10/*.snappy.parquet* (overwrites previous day's files), the Glue job will produce additive data in the output folder, i.e. it'll contain data from yesterday's run, plus today's run (so 10/1 data twice, and 10/2 data). On next day, it'd be 10/1 data 3X, 10/2 data 2X, and 10/3 data. And so on. Data for 2020/09 and before are ok since they didn't change. Below is the basic structure of my code with boiler plate code removed and real transformation replaced by contrived one.

```
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "mydatabase", table_name = "mydata", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0")
ds_df = DataSource0.toDF()
ds_df1 = ds_df.select("year","month",upper(col('colA')),upper(col('colB')),upper(col('colC')),upper(col('colD')))
Transform0 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(ds_df1, glueContext, "Transform0")
DataSink0 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = Transform0, connection_type = "s3", format = "parquet", connection_options = {"path": "s3://<bucket>/mydata-transformed/", "partitionKeys": ["year","month"]}, transformation_ctx = "DataSink0")
job.commit()
```

What can I do to make it so that for the current month, previous day' data is deleted and replaced by data from the current job? Is there a way to know that, in my example, that the *month=10* partition in the source data has changed, and therefore I can purge the same partition in the output before doing the transformations and output new data?

Thanks.

[Edit]
So it seems one solution would be to get the job bookmark and then use the CURR_LATEST_PARTITIONS value to determine which partition I should delete before processing the data. In my case, CURR_LATEST_PARTITIONS is 2020/09 when I'm processing 2020/10. So I know to delete the data for 2020/10, since that has to be the data that's being processed for if CURR_LATEST_PARTITIONS is 2020/09. I don't really like this solution, but I think it'll work and I'm not sure what else I could do.

Comment: Since I dont have enough reputation to comment , adding to address the concerns in comments about the third option purge_s3_path in accepted answer. Its proably not working because by default the 'retention period' is 7 days, meaning anything newer than 168 hours wont be deleted by purge_s3_path. So you need to specify the retention to zero for a path if you wish to delete it like below : glueContext.purge_s3_path('s3://s3_path/bucket', options={"retentionPeriod":0})

Comment: @Deepak Gaur, thank you! Your answer worked.

Comment: @DeepakGaur I tried keeping the retention period to 0. The script did run successfully, but the file in the s3 path did not get deleted. Any reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. DynamicFrameWriter doesn't support overwriting data in S3 yet. Instead you can use Spark native `write()`. However, for really large datasets it can be a bit inefficient as a single worker will be used to overwrite existing data in S3. An example is below:

```
    sc = SparkContext()
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    spark = glueContext.spark_session
    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")
    
    job = Job(glueContext)
    job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
    
    DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "mydatabase", table_name = "mydata", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0")
    ds_df = DataSource0.toDF()
    ds_df1 = ds_df.select("year","month",upper(col('colA')),upper(col('colB')),upper(col('colC')),upper(col('colD')))
    ds_df1 \
        .write.mode('overwrite') \
        .format('parquet') \
        .partitionBy('year', 'month') \
        .save('s3://<bucket>/mydata-transformed/')
    
    job.commit()
```

2. In the lambda function, you could use delete data in S3 under a certain prefix. An example using Python and boto3 is:

```
    import boto3
    
    s3_res = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = 'my-bucket-name'
    # Add any logic to derive required prefix based on year/month/day
    prefix = 'mydata/year=2020/month=10/'
    s3_res.Bucket(bucket).objects.filter(Prefix=key).delete()
```

3. You can use Glue's `purge_s3_path` to delete data from a certain prefix. Link is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context-purge_s3_path).

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't get purge_s3_path to work, but the first solution worked for me after I additionally also added the following:

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")

Comment: purge_s3_path() doesnt work for me either. Dont know why

Comment: The `purge_s3_path` worked fine for me. You need to set the retention period to zero. `glueContext.purge_s3_path( f"s3://{args['s3_bucket']}/archive/resources/date={today}", options={"retentionPeriod": 0})`

Answer (score 3):

now exist a function in glue for delete S3 path or delete glue catalog table.

[AWS GLue doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context-purge_table)

Answer (score 3):

You can use purge_s3_path.

Note that it wont work right out of the box because by default the 'retention period' is 7 days, meaning anything newer than 168 hours wont be deleted by purge_s3_path. So you need to specify the retention to zero for a path if you wish to delete it like below :

```
glueContext.purge_s3_path('s3://s3_path/bucket', options={"retentionPeriod":0})
```